# Why is the image not displaying in php and random symbols appearing instead

Tags: php, html, image

I have the webserver and the sql server working fin but when i run the file no image is displayed and characters like �})>�}(���>��j|��0�Ry>�s appear instead. What am i missing? the cobe below is part of the page.

```
    <body>
         <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $passw = "Ajax3617";
    $dbname="sailingdb";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $passw, $dbname);

    $sql = "SELECT picturefile FROM pictures";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {

echo '<img src="'.$row['picturefile'].'" width="175" height="200" />';

    } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible that `$row['picturefile']` contains the actual image data and not the path to the file?

Comment: What is the type of `picturefile` field? BLOB?

Comment: Show us the output of the following two queries, `DESCRIBE pictures; SELECT picturefile FROM pictures;`

Comment: picturefile is a BLOB

Comment: So you must treat it as a BLOB, i.e. write it as stream but filepath

Comment: howdo i change it to a stream?

Answer (score 1):

If the data in `$row['picturefile']` is base64 encoded you could display it with the following:

```
echo '<img src="'.'data:image/png;base64,'.$row['picturefile'].'" width="175" height="200" />';
```